# Autosummary: How to control which methods are used in generated docs?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using sphinx to generate my documentation and the `autosummary` extension takes care of generating little stubs for all classes not explicitly written by myself.

Take the class `Foo` and assume it has a mixin `Base` that adds more methods very basic methods that are for storage. They are not private since they might be of use but only to 1% of the users. An also the mixin is present in about all classes that I use. Main point is that the mixin in necessary but documenting it in all classes just clutters the docs and I want to only mention that is uses the Base mixin in the class description, but hide the actual methods and attributes.

Using `autodoc` I can remove documenting these functions using a custom `autodoc-skip-member`. This works but only affects the extended documentation of each method, not the listing of the inherited methods in the beginning.

Now `autosummary` will put all of these in the stubs and does not use any `autodoc` settings. I hacked the `autosummary` code to actually do what I want, but this is truly not elegant.

My questions would be:

1. Are there other ways to generate these files?
2. Are these files meant to be generated everytime the docs are build or is it more a *generate the stubs once and edit by hand to your liking* approach. That would make sense although I would rather have this automated.
3. Can `autosummary` be adapted in a more reusable way to do what I want?
4. From a programmers point of view: Is it good practice to hide the inherited (even if almost never used) functions at all?

The generated content looks like this

```
foo.Foo
=======

.. currentmodule:: foo

.. autoclass:: foo

   .. automethod:: __init__

   .. rubric:: Methods

   .. autosummary::

      ~Foo.method1
      ~Foo.method2
      ~Foo.inherited_method_from_Base1  # remove
      ~Foo.inherited_method_from_Base2  # remove

   .. rubric:: Attributes

   .. autosummary::

      ~Foo.attribute1
      ~Foo.attribute2
      ~Foo.inherited_attribute_from_Base1  # remove
      ~Foo.inherited_attribute_from_Base2  # remove
```

Comment: How exactly did you generate the file?